# How can I append multiple copies of a value to a Python bytearray?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-bytearray

If I have a Python list (`data`) and two integers (`i` and `count`), I can easily append `count` copies of `i` to `data`:

```
>>> data = [0]
>>> i, count = 1, 4
>>> data += [i] * count
>>> data
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

How can I do the same if `data` is a `bytearray`? Is it necessary to create a list first, e.g. `data += bytearray([i] * count)`?

Comment: Did you try anything? If it didn't work, what's the code & error? I don't see any `bytearray`'s in the code provided to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it necessary to create a list first, e.g. `data += bytearray([i] * count)`?

That is indeed one way to do it. You can do the multiply operation on the byte array (as opposed to the list), which is slightly more memory-efficient and *much* faster for large values of `count`*:

```python
>>> data = bytearray([0])
>>> i, count = 1, 4
>>> data += bytearray((i,)) * count
>>> data
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01')
```

* source: Works on my machine; YMMV! Tried with a count of 4000000000, which went out of memory when multiplying the list, but not when multiplying the bytearray. Smaller values of `count` (600000000) use more than 8 times as much memory when multiplying a list than when multiplying a bytearray.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using `import` i would suggest `itertools.repeat`.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> data = bytearray([0])
>>> data.extend(repeat(1, 3))
>>> data
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x01\x01')
```

Comment: I would like to contest the "fast" assertion - on my machine it is more than 27 times slower than naive multiplication when testing with 6000000000 iterations:  http://i.imgur.com/6utNJVc.png The gap seems to worsen with larger numbers too, though that is probably in part due to python's warmup time being taken out of the equation.

Comment: @Score_Under, on small N itertools is _up_  _to_ :) 40%  faster on my machine 
    `In [32]: %timeit s=bytearray(); s.extend(repeat(1, 1000000))`<br/>
    `100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop`

    `In [33]: %timeit bytearray([1]*1000000)`
    `100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop`
On such huge numbers i guess the slowdown is due to swapping in array reallocation.

Comment: you need to multiply the bytearray rather than the list - list multiplication is probably the least efficient way to do this, which is why I steered away from it quickly in my answer. For some reason I can't @-mention you, is this a bug?

Comment: @Score_Under, You are completly right; just tested `15.2ms` vs `317µs`. And my assertion about O(1) memory may be also wrong cause  the growing array needs to be realloced, wich often involves malloc+memcpy+free